# Insert splitted string into a list in python

Tags: python

consider this piece of code:

```
csvreader = csv.reader(filter(lambda row: row[0] != '#', fcsv), delimiter= '\t')
csvrs =[[row[2], row[7]] for row in csvreader]
```

the element `row[7]` is a string separated by `;`, what i want to do is not put the entire `row[7]` inside csvrs but only a splitted part seaprated by `;`

Say for example:

```
row[7] = '123;457;789;1011'
```

i want only the second position inside csvrs (in this case 457) and i want this every time filtering out every other piece. I'M trying with split with no result maintaining the list comprehension.

Comment: How are you using `.split()`, and what does it do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just do the split inside the comprehension and get `[1]` for the second item

```
csvrs =[[row[2], row[7].split(';')[1]] for row in csvreader]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_second_col(row, delimiter=';'):
    try:
        return row.split(delimeter)[1]
    except IndexError:
        return None

csvrs =[[row[2], get_second_col(row[7])] for row in csvreader]
```